# How to add element into a form and load it to dialog box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to dynamically inject a link a link into a form using jQuery & WordPress. The form is located in a WordPress post and I use `$.load('url').dialog()` to display it. This works fine.

I wish to add a link that is calculated on the fly. I have a special id for the element that I wish to modify, but `append()`, `appendTo()` and `replaceWith()` all result with the single element and NOT the whole form with the modification embedded inside.

Preferably, the calculated value is set *into* an input field.

```
jQuery('<div />').load(url).find("#my-special-id").append('<a href="' + order + '">link to your order</a>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `load()` is asynchronous, so you're trying to find the `#my-special-id` element before it exists in the DOM.

To fix this use the callback of `load()` to execute your logic *after* the AJAX request completes:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('<div />').load(url, function() {
    $("#my-special-id").append('<a href="' + order + '">link to your order</a>')
  });
});
```

Comment: I did try similar sync. with $.get but will give it a try - THANKS!

Comment: Don't forget you'll also need to add the `div` element you create to the DOM as well.

Comment: This is exactly where I fail... I need: load() or get(), modify() (= add value to an input field, with the above id) and finally open in a dialog().

But the whole sequence is not working for me. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You've not really described what you're trying to do so it's hard to help. All I can say is that you're calling `load()` on a `div` which only exists in memory, it won't be shown on the page unless you add it. I have no idea what input field you're referring to.

Comment: I will try to elaborate more. The final result is a from the will trigger email witha specific link and visitor info.

The code:

  ```jQuery('<div />' ).load( site_url + '/send-email/', function() {
       jQuery("#my-special-id").val()= 'link to visitor order';
       jQuery(this).dialog({... });
  });```

This is not working but I hope that I outlined what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Rory, any suggestions for my solution above?

Comment: No sorry, that's still not clear. I'd suggest editing much more detail in to the question, or starting a new one

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works.
The idea is to use open event to manipulate the html prior to display. Simple & readable. Thanks to @Rory McCrossan for putting me on the right direction.

```
     jQuery('<div />' ).load( url, function() {
            jQuery(this).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            open: function(){jQuery("#my-on-the-fly-order-link").val('link-to-order') },
            ... // more stuff
```

During open event I can do whatever is needed and it is readable.